# Quick View field should fetch through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have a **QuickView form** on Case form . 
I want to fetch a attribute value from Quckview form through Javascript .
I want email value should popup . But It is not working 
**Related entity name is : Acount
QuickView form name is :customerpane_qfc
attribute name is :emailaddress1**
I'm using this code

```
alert(Xrm.Page.getControl("MyQuickView_MyQuickView_systemuser_mobilephone").getAttribute().getValue());
```

but this code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For getting a control in a Quick View Form with JavaScript, you use a [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#Anchor_3) of `"quickViewFormName_quickViewFormName_relatedEntityName_fieldName"`.

- `quickViewFormName` is the name of the Quick View Control on your form (and yes, it should be repeated twice).
- `relatedEntityName` is the name of the related entity.
- `fieldName` is the name of the field in the related entity.

In your case you would thus do as follows (assuming the naming of your quick view form is as you write):

```js
Xrm.Page.getControl("customerpane_qfc_customerpane_qfc_account_emailaddress1")
.getAttribute()
.getValue();
```